# Tweak JSON or GSON?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a Java app that is getting back the following JSON from a 3rd party RESTful web service:

```
{
    "widgets":[
        [
            {
                "id":25128,
                "status":"always",
                "uuid":"96f62edd-fa8a-4267-8ffb-14af0d37de26"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "id":25200,
                "status":"always",
                "uuid":"78553c9e-398f-495a-8fb8-ada0fb297844"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "id":25128,
                "status":"never",
                "uuid":"b1e3deb2-a842-4cba-8272-458d15efb394"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

And trying to convert it into a `List<Widget>` using GSON:

```
public class Widget {
    @SerializedName("id")
    private Long id;

    @SerializedName("status")
    private String status;

    @SerializedName("uuid")
    private String uuid;

    // Getters & setters, etc.
}
```

Here is my mapper code:

```
String jsonResponse = getJsonFromWebService();
Gson gson = new Gson();
List<Widget> widgets = gson.fromJson(jsonResponse, new TypeToken<List<Widget>>(){}.getType());
```

When I run this, I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2
```

Obviously, I either need to manipulate the JSON string before sending it to my GSON mapper code, or I need to configure GSON to handle the "unexpected" JSON, but I'm not sure which is easier/more appropriate. If I need to "massage" the JSON string, not sure what I need to do to make GSON play nicely with it. And if I need to configure GSON, not sure what to do there either. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Each of the elements in the JSON array of widgets is itself an array with a single element - your deserialization logic does not account for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong is that you're ignoring the root JSON Object with a single JSON Property "widgets". Try deserializing your data into this object instead:

```
public class WidgetList {
    @SerializedName("widgets")
    private List<List<Widget>> widgets;
}
```

Comment: And `new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<List<Widget>>>(){}.getType());`

Comment: Nice suggestion @jsn but it actually didn't work. I had to just use `new Gson().fromJson(json, WidgetList.class)` and that worked fine.

Comment: `{ "items" : [ 1, 2, 3 ] }` does *not* deserialize to `List<int>`, but `[ 1, 2, 3 ]` does.  You can't ignore the top-level object with single property.

Answer (score 0):

Massaging it to the below format works for me

```
[
    {
       'id':25128,
       'status':'always',
       'uuid':'96f62edd-fa8a-4267-8ffb-14af0d37de26'                                                           },       
    {
        'id':25200,
        'status':'always',
        'uuid':'78553c9e-398f-495a-8fb8-ada0fb297844'                                           },
    {   'id':25128,
        'status':'never',
        'uuid':'b1e3deb2-a842-4cba-8272-458d15efb394'   
}
]
```

As the below demonstrates

```
public class TryMe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Gson gson = new Gson();
        List<Widget> widgets = gson.fromJson(json,
                new TypeToken<List<Widget>>() {
                }.getType());

        System.out.println(widgets);
    }
}

class Widget {
    @SerializedName("id")
    private Long id;

    @SerializedName("status")
    private String status;

    @SerializedName("uuid")
    private String uuid;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Widget [id=" + id + ", status=" + status + ", uuid=" + uuid
                + "]";
    }   
}
```

Giving the below resp

```
[Widget [id=25128, status=always, uuid=96f62edd-fa8a-4267-8ffb-14af0d37de26], Widget [id=25200, status=always, uuid=78553c9e-398f-495a-8fb8-ada0fb297844], Widget [id=25128, status=never, uuid=b1e3deb2-a842-4cba-8272-458d15efb394]]
```